# sscanf pointer vs variable address

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

The following code works.

```
unsigned int i1;unsigned int i2;
float *v1;float *v2;
sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0","%u %u %f",&i1,&i2,v1,v2);
printf("%f",v1);
```

Add in another %f, the following does not work. It compiles but I get 
bash: [9612: 1 (255)] tcsetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device.

```
unsigned int i1;unsigned int i2;
float *v1;float *v2;
sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0","%u %u %f %f",&i1,&i2,v1,v2);
```

Why?!

Comment: You need to let `v1` and `v2` point to valid memory. Otherwise, your programme has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question changed!

<s>Your first code should fail; you need to pass `&v1` and there's no point in passing `v2` since it is (a) not an address and (b) there's no conversion specification for it anyway.</s>

The first code should fail because you're not passing an initialized pointer in `v1`, and there's no point in passing `v2` since it is neither initialized nor used by the format string.  When you pass uninitialized pointers to `sscanf()`, you invoke undefined behaviour, and any response is acceptable — a catastrophic failure (wiping your disk?), or benign almost as expected behaviour (even though there are no good grounds for expecting such benign behaviour).  Similar comments apply to most functions; don't pass uninitialized pointers around; it is very seldom that any good comes of doing so.

The second fails because you're not passing initialized addresses.

Corrected code 1:

```
unsigned int i1;
unsigned int i2;
float f1;
float *v1 = &f1;
if (sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0", "%u %u %f", &i1, &i2, v1) == 3)
    printf("%f\n", *v1);
```

(Unused variable `v2` removed.)

Alternative 1:

```
unsigned int i1;
unsigned int i2;
float v1;
if (sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0", "%u %u %f", &i1, &i2, &v1) == 3)
    printf("%f\n", v1);
```

(No pointer variables.)

Corrected code 2:

```
unsigned int i1;
unsigned int i2;
float v1;  // Not pointer
float v2;  // Not pointer
if (sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0", "%u %u %f %f", &i1, &i2, &v1, &v2) == 4)
    printf("%f %f\n", v1, v2);
```

Or:

```
unsigned int i1;
unsigned int i2;
float f1;
float f2;
float *v1 = &v1;  // Initialized pointer
float *v2 = &v2;  // Initialized pointer
if (sscanf("1 1 2.0 3.0", "%u %u %f %f", &i1, &i2, v1, v2) == 4)
    printf("%f %f\n", f1, f2);  // Or *v1, *v2
```

I think the version without the pointer variables is more sensible.

Note the test to ensure that the conversions worked!

Comment: It was just bad luck that it didn't fail.  You invoked undefined behaviour.  When you do that, anything can happen, including catastrophic failures or behaviour that almost matches what you expected.  Anything is possible.